# How to show web page/web resource in CRM Dynamics?

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am new to Microsoft Dynamics. I managed to create new solution and know how to add web resource to particular page like Contacts. Also, I have added few buttons to Ribbon control with their actions.

Now my problem is, I want to add a button either to ribbon control or anywhere in page, which I can access in complete CRM (like I can do in Master Page of asp.net), and which will help me open my web resource.

For example, if I click on Charts bar, web resource should be visible, otherwise it should be hidden.

[image]

My question may be lame, because I am very new to CRM Dynamics, kindly suggest my way is correct or I need to take some different approach?

Comment: What action will the button perform? A CRM action / link, or trigger something outside CRM? Have you look into adding Javascript to the page? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx

Comment: @Kye I want to show web resource..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you're looking for a way to add a button to multiple screens without need to modify each of them separately. (To avoid the pain when modifying all the ribbons or all the forms.)

In that case I'd suggest creating a separate JS web resource with code that adds a button with desired functionality, styling etc. And use Form Libraries Manager from [XrmToolbox](http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/) to bulk add the resource to all the forms.